# How to debug Emacs crashes on OSX

Tags: bash, emacs, elisp

A new version of Emacs Trunk is crashing under certain circumstances, and I'm having trouble figuring out how to submit a proper debug report that starts Emacs from `src`.  I assume that this means the `src` folder of the Emacs Trunk download -- e.g., `.../emacs-trunk/src` .

I found a bash script on Emacs Wiki that looks like it comes close to doing what needs to be done, except that it is not set up for OSX -- e.g., I don't think I have a `gnome-terminal` on OSX 10.6.8.  Any pointers on how to fix this debugging script to properly launch Emacs from the `src` directory would be greatly appreciated:

```
#!/bin/sh
 if [[ "$1" == "--debug" ]]; then
     shift
     /Users/HOME/.0.data/.0.emacs/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs $* &
     EMACS_PID=$!
     cd /Users/HOME/Desktop/emacs-trunk/src/
     gnome-terminal --termname xterm --use-factory --start-factory-server --title "Debug Emacs" --execute gdb /Users/HOME/.0.data/.0.emacs/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs $EMACS_PID &
 else
     /Users/HOME/.0.data/.0.emacs/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs $* &
 fi
```

---

**EDIT**:  Here is a revised bash script.  I'm on the right track -- just need to figure out how to include `bt` so that it automatically generates a full backtrace when Emacs crashes.

```
#!/bin/sh
 if [[ "$1" == "--debug" ]]; then
     shift
     /Users/HOME/.0.data/.0.emacs/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs $* &
     EMACS_PID=$!
     cd /Users/HOME/Desktop/emacs-trunk-01-01-2014/src/
     gdb /Users/HOME/.0.data/.0.emacs/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs $EMACS_PID &
 else
     /Users/HOME/.0.data/.0.emacs/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs $* &
 fi
```

Comment: I've never tried to debug a crash (hardly happens and when it did, it was because of a package not playing well with others)... anyways, have you looked at the stack trace produced by emacs?  (see http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Crashing.html) or are you saying that the stack trace isn't produced on OSX?

Comment: See a more recent read in another forum that contains an answer:  http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/14354/how-do-i-debug-an-emacs-crash